# Pandas inheritance causes infinite recursion error

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, stack-overflow

I am trying to wrap Pandas's data frame to extend it with more functionality, for example here I am trying to have self._number_cols include the numeric columns. The example below ends with a recursion error.

p.s.
I defined the _constructor according to the guide here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html

```
import pandas as pd


class MyDf(pd.DataFrame):
    _metadata = ['number_cols']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDf

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return pd.Series

    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
                 copy=False):
        super().__init__(data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
        self._number_cols = self.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mydf = MyDf({'a': [1, 2], 'b': ['a', 'b']})
    print(mydf._number_cols)
```

Error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2018.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 17, in __init__
    self._number_cols = self.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3091, in select_dtypes
    return self.loc[com._get_info_slice(self, dtype_indexer)]
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 890, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1868, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1498, in _getbool_axis
    raise self._exception(detail)
KeyError: KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(KeyError(RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison',),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),),)
R
```